# Logback stops working when upgrading to Tomcat 10.1

Tags: java, tomcat, logback, java.util.logging

I have a war (built with Java 8) that's using Logback. This is working well in Tomcat 9.0.* but now I want to deploy it on Tomcat 10.1 and the logging from my app is not working. I can see Tomcat's log messages from java.util.logging, like `org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory`, but nothing from my app.

My dependencies are:

- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11
- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11
- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36
- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.36

Setting `<configuration debug="true"` in my logback.xml didn't produce anything, and neither did setting logback.configurationFile parameter manually.

How can I debug this? Maybe enabling a particular logger in Tomcat?

I know there are other problems in my app (javax - jakarta issue), I don't think they would cause this logback issue... without logging it will be hard to fix the other issues.

*Edit:* The Tomcat starts well with Java 11, just my war is built with Java 8 and the war seems to deploy successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In the tomcat documentation for vers 10.1.X :

> Applications that run on Tomcat 9 and earlier will not run on Tomcat
> 10 without changes. Java EE based applications designed for Tomcat 9
> and earlier may be placed in the $CATALINA_BASE/webapps-javaee
> directory and Tomcat will automatically convert them to Jakarta EE and
> copy them to the webapps directory. This conversion is performed using
> the Apache Tomcat migration tool for Jakarta EE tool which is also
> available as a separate download for off-line use.
> https://tomcat.apache.org/

I think deploying the war to the **webapps-javaee** directory instead of the **webapps** directory will solve your problem